# Is it possible to compile compile .asn files to Golang code?

Tags: go, asn.1

Is there a proper way to compile a .asn file spec to Golang code ? I made it with C and Rust, but can't find anything for Golang (while it also supports a subset of ASN.1 spec in the standard library).

Comment: What do you mean by  “compile”? The asn1 package has tools for encoding and encoding https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/asn1. You would have to look into 3rd party packages to find an implementation covering more of the asn.1 specification.

Comment: What would it mean to "compile a .asn file spec to Go code"? ASN describes syntax, it's declarative. Go code executes, it's procedural.

Comment: Sorry for my brief question. Yes, I mean generating golang code from ASN specs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean: is there a tool that generates Golang code from ASN.1 specs ?

A Google search only shows one: https://www.obj-sys.com/products/asn1c/index.php

The encoding/asn1 go package is for very specific uses and will not help you (unless you decide to write your own compiler and use encoding/asn1 at runtime)